# what different things can you graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

I am trying to learn graph as many thing as possible, without using calculator. It will help me a lot if some one can give me more topics. So i can learn how to graph them.

- line
- parabola
- sin/cos/tan
- circle

Comment: Try [this google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22curve+sketching%22+-derivative+-calculus), which is a search for the phrase "curve sketching" that omits the words "derivative" and "calculus". If you want examples that make use of calculus, then don't omit those words (you may even want to include them).

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

$y = x^4 - 2x^2 + x - 3$ (polynomials)

$y = a^x$ (exponential function)

$a x^2 + b y^2 = c$ (ellipse or hyperbola)

$y = x+a/x$ (another hyperbola)

$y = (x^3-x)/(x^2+1)$ (or rational functions in general)

$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ (standard normal distribution)

Try everything you can think of! And you can check your drawings with a free graph software at http://www.padowan.dk/